# order of a binary search tree that prints itself in preorder

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm studying for a test, and I found this question.

Given that a binary tree preorder print (print,recursive call left,recursive call right) method gave the following output:

```
{10, 8, 1, 9, 12, 15, 14}
```

How is the tree built if we know it's a **binary search tree**?

So if I'm not wrong, it has to be like this:

```
      10
     /  \
   8     12 
 /   \    \
1    9     15
            \
             14
```

Is it correct?

Comment: It is incorrect if it is a binary tree. The 14 should be `left child` of 15.

Comment: A convenient bullet list of traits can be found in the first paragraph of the wikipedia article; "The left is lower than the parent, the right is greater than the parent."

Answer (score 3):

It is incorrect because the tree must hold its search capability meaning that it must keep a constant form. By having node 14 the right child we lose this form. 14 should be the left child to node 15. If you look at node 8 we see that if the value is less than 8, it is to the left, else the value is the right child.

```
            10
           /  \
          8    12
         / \    \
        1   9   15
                /
               14
```

Comment: Good explanation, also check out https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html

Answer (score 2):

In binary search tree left child should be lower than his parent and right child is greater than his parent, because of that `14` should be left chile of `15`

```
      10
     /  \
   8     12 
 /   \    \
1    9     15
           /
          14
```

**[HERE](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/9.BST.html)** you can find a good explanation of BST